# std::future returned from std::async hangs while going out of scope

Tags: c++, c++11, stdasync, std-future

I am using a combination of `std::async` and `std::future` from `C++ 11`. I am using to enforce a time_out on a certain activity that I do in my code which **might** take time as I try connecting to server.

Following is how the code is:

```
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

std::size_t PotentiallyLongRunningActivity() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10000s);
    return 10;
}

bool DoActivity() {

  bool activity_done = false;
  auto my_future_result(std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
      return PotentiallyLongRunningActivity(); //returns size_t
  }));

  std::future_status my_future_status = my_future_result.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(800));
  if (my_future_status == std::future_status::timeout) {
      activity_done = false;
  }
  else if (my_future_status == std::future_status::ready) {
      if (my_future_result.valid() && my_future_result.get() > 0) {
          activity_done = true;
      }
  }

  return activity_done;
  //my_future_result hangs while exiting this method !!!
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DoActivity();
    return 0;
}
```

Things work fine in most of the cases. The future times out & is reported ready in many cases. But, Strange behavior I am observing is that in some cases the UI hangs because `my_future_result` when going out of scope hangs. I confirmed this by repeating the call to `my_future_result.get()` which never returns if called just before exiting the method.

How can I get around this ? Is there some way I cancel or delete or terminate the `std::future` ?

Comment: That said, I'd recommend you to create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there a chance your future is not valid prior to the wait call?

Comment: Async tasks block until the task is finished, upon destruction. It's like running `wait` when going out of scope.

Comment: it is really strange behavior with the future & async. this is only a pseudocode btw. The call to `PotentiallyLongRunningActivity` in my actual source code in is trying to connect to a server using boost::asio. but as You would understand, I cannot give put the whole source code here on stactOverflow. But as per my understanding, the future should cancel the call after time out & should not hang after that.

Comment: Based on my reading of the docs on cppreference, hitting the timeout will not kill the task.

Comment: @MikelF how can I kill the task ?

Comment: @SegmentationFault check example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future. You can `detach` from threads, and you can create a `task` (to obtain a `future`) in a `thread`. In sum you need to `detach`. The example there shows two ways of having a `future` to come from a detached `thread`.

Comment: at least with C# TPLs you have to use signals to terminate... likely you must also do that here... but from what your describing, your actual function that your waiting on may itself be blocking.  Especially if something establishing a remote connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking from [cppreference sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280364/stdfuture-returned-from-stdasync-hangs-while-going-out-of-scope/42280984?noredirect=1#comment71718404_42280364), only "the start", "f2 finished" and "the end" will get printed from this code (because `f1` doesn't "hang"):

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;

    {
        std::packaged_task<int()> task([]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
            std::cout << "f1 finished" << std::endl;
            return 42;
        });
        std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();
        std::thread(std::move(task)).detach();

        std::future<int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
            std::cout << "f2 finished" << std::endl;
            return 42;
        });

        f1.wait_for(1s);
        f2.wait_for(1s);
        std::cout << "the start" << std::endl;
    }

    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(7s);
    std::cout << "the end" << std::endl;
}
```

For good discussion see: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html.

C++ standard library gives no support for thread kill operations.

Take care with threads you `detach`. Detachment per se is not "extremely bad", it may be useful in user terminable daemons for example, or if you have some other idea of orchestration and teardown. Otherwise, `detach` would have no point being provided by the standard library.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of a use of `detach` that isn't bad (as in dangerous/UB)?  I'm aware of "make ready at thread exit", but that doesn't seem to be what you are talking about.  Well, you can get the native thread id and basically do a join via that...

Comment: The link to the discussion makes this answer extra useful.

Answer (score 6):

You are exiting your function before the `std::async` task has completed. Under certain circumstances, the destructor for a `std::future` will block until the task has completed.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for

Here in the documentation for `wait_for` the example shows multiple calls to `wait_for` after timeouts, showing that the act of timing out does not cancel the `std::async` task.

There is no built-in support (that I could discover) that allows for threads to be killed externally. This makes sense as there isn't a way to properly clean up the state of system resources in use by the thread if it is terminated in this way.

Instead, it is better to place the timeout logic in the thread itself, so that it can terminate itself and clean up properly.

Comment: ok. this is some good information. at least I understand why the damn thing is getting blocked. but this is crazy. if I am getting blocked by the destructor then whats the point of the time_out. is there preferred way to do this other than the code I have posted ?

Comment: @SegmentationFault [detach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280364/stdfuture-returned-from-stdasync-hangs-while-going-out-of-scope#comment71718404_42280364)

Comment: @pepper_chico there is no call to detach in `my_future_result`.

Comment: @SegmentationFault in c++ thread objects going out of scope without detach will terminate your program. Task will block it. The other option is explicit detachment, there's no thread killing.

Comment: @SegmentationFault just learn from the example on cppreference, it's pretty clear and minimal.

Comment: @SegmentationFault this is good material to learn more about http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, losing track of a thread is extremely bad.  Having code running in another thread when `main` exits is a recipie of undefined behavior.

As such, the `std::future` that returns from `std::async` has the special property that it will wait for the `std::async` to complete when it is destroyed.

This is what you are describing as a "hang".  It isn't a hang -- it is waiting for the task to complete.

Threading primitives in C++11 are primitives; they are not finished types for a full featured application.  You can use them to write thread pools deferred task queues and the like; using them naively "in the raw" tends to result in them biasing towards correctness, but not giving you what you want.

A simple thread pool is just:

```
template<class T>
struct threaded_queue {
  using lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;
  void push_back( T t ) {
    {
      lock l(m);
      data.push_back(std::move(t));
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  boost::optional<T> pop_front() {
    lock l(m);
    cv.wait(l, [this]{ return abort || !data.empty(); } );
    if (abort) return {};
    auto r = std::move(data.back());
    data.pop_back();
    return std::move(r);
  }
  void terminate() {
    {
      lock l(m);
      abort = true;
      data.clear();
    }
    cv.notify_all();
  }
  ~threaded_queue()
  {
    terminate();
  }
private:
  std::mutex m;
  std::deque<T> data;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  bool abort = false;
};
struct thread_pool {
  thread_pool( std::size_t n = 1 ) { start_thread(n); }
  thread_pool( thread_pool&& ) = delete;
  thread_pool& operator=( thread_pool&& ) = delete;
  ~thread_pool() = default; // or `{ terminate(); }` if you want to abandon some tasks
  template<class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>>
  std::future<R> queue_task( F task ) {
    std::packaged_task<R()> p(std::move(task));
    auto r = p.get_future();
    tasks.push_back( std::move(p) );
    return r;
  }
  template<class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>>
  std::future<R> run_task( F task ) {
    if (threads_active() >= total_threads()) {
      start_thread();
    }
    return queue_task( std::move(task) );
  }
  void terminate() {
    tasks.terminate();
  }
  std::size_t threads_active() const {
    return active;
  }
  std::size_t total_threads() const {
    return threads.size();
  }
  void clear_threads() {
    terminate();
    threads.clear();
  }
  void start_thread( std::size_t n = 1 ) {
    while(n-->0) {
      threads.push_back(
        std::async( std::launch::async,
          [this]{
            while(auto task = tasks.pop_front()) {
              ++active;
              try{
                (*task)();
              } catch(...) {
                --active;
                throw;
              }
              --active;
            }
          }
        )
      );
    }
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::future<void>> threads;
  threaded_queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> tasks;
  std::atomic<std::size_t> active;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3841284898c85597).

Now you create some thread pool somewhere, toss tasks at it, and you can wait on the futures in question.  There is a bounded number of threads in the pool.

`run_task` will ensure there is a thread to run any task you queue.  `queue_task` will use only existing threads if available.

The returned `std::future<void>` does not block for the task to complete; but the `thread_pool` object's destructor does.

Note that it will abort all queued tasks, and wait for currently runing tasks to complete, by default on destruction.

Something that wraps a `unique_ptr<thread_pool>` is useful to permit ease of moving.  Moving has to be disabled because active threads keep a pointer-to-`this`.

`thread_pool` is not thread safe ironically; this is because we don't guard the `std::vector<std::future<void>> threads;`; I mean, other than thread safe with regard to the threads itself stores.  It is designed to be directly accessed by only one external thread.

`queue_task` and `terminate` is thread safe mostly by accident.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is because the compiler was not told that the result of your function DoModify() will be available asynchronously ( hence to be declared as std::future<> ) and it expected a synchronous result of bool type which didn't arrive so. You can use std::future::is_ready() or std::future_status . Here a sample code snippet

```
 std::future<size_t> DoActivity()
 {
      return std::async(std::launch::async, []()
            {
             return PotentiallyLongRunningActivity(); 
            });
 }

 int main()
 {
     auto result = DoActivity();
     if ( result. Is_ready() )
     {
         auto data = result.get();
         //do something with data
     }
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your suggestion. an object of `std::future<size_t>` does not have method `IsReady` to check ready status.  but nevertheless, if you see the code in my question, I doing the call to `get`, it is done under the case of `std::future_status::ready`. Do you still consider my code to be wrong ?

Comment: @Segmentation Fault: I have edited and elaborated my answer. Your code has a major flaw and needs to be corrected.