# Distributing a for loop over an arbitrary number of threads based on varying hardware

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop

I want to distribute the workload of a for loop over an arbitrary number of threads.

```
unsigned hardwareThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
std::vector<std::thread> threads(hardwareThreads);

double bigList[n]

void worker() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // do work on big list
    }
}
```

I want to AVOID manually defining a separate worker function to do even chunks of what worker does:

```
threads[0](worker1)
threads[1](worker3)
threads[2](worker2)
etc...
```

I want to provide a loop with the number of threads available, and have it divide up the loop into that many even sized loops.

I'm working on an answer and will post it soon. I realized this isn't very hard.

Comment: See if you can use OpenMP. It has a set of `#pragma` commands which can automatically run subsets of your loops on threads.

Comment: Your inner loop appears to allow many iterations of the loop to read or alter the positions of the same balls. The algorithm doesn't appear to be parallelizable as-is. At least, you'll have to synchronize positions. This will be tricky, because all you do is operate over positions.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) to get a hint at the number of threads you should run. It's widely supported, but platforms are allowed to return 0 instead.

Comment: If I remember rightly, it seems some game code did vector intersections and made a list of colliding objects. Then at the end it went back and did fine tuned precise collision.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am using the hardware_concurrency function. Definitely vital to my goal, but now I need to know how to divide up the work to an arbitrary number of threads based on what that function returns. Also to your first comment, the outer loop can be paralellized without issue. I don't plan to parallelize the inner loop. I'm writing a simpler code example to replace so it is clearer what I need.

Comment: The problem I described is that if you divide the outer loop, each thread's inner loop can interfer with other threads' inner loop. The data is shared and operations overlap on it

Comment: I would advice to look at the cookie-cutter solution - Intel TBB with their task groups, scheduling etc. https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

Comment: Seems like the exact type of thing you'd offload to the GPU

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are right. Thanks. I just noticed that it can potentially randomize the location of a ball in multiple threads. I'll move them in a separate loop afterward. I'm going to simplify the code now to get at the problem I really want to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The basic shape of your work is a triangle -- each inner loop does n-1, n-2, n-3, ..., 1 steps.

So the first step will be to linearize the triangle, or otherwise divide it into K equal sized groups.

Suppose we have a function from i to a triangle position:

```
struct ball_pair { int ball, other_ball; };

ball_pair get_ball_pair( int i ); // TODO
int get_pair_count( int n ) { return n*(n-1)/2; }
```

now we rewrite your code to read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < get_pair_count(n); ++i) {
  auto&& [Ball, otherBall] = get_ball_pair(i);
  // your code
}
```

this code is *almost* in good shape to be made parallel.  The next problem is you are mutating the sequence as you work on it.

Defer the mutation until later; instead of mutating directly, track the balls you want to mutate, and mutate them in a batch.

An easy way would be a vector of char (not bools, that isn't thread safe) which is non-zero if and only if you want to reroll a ball's location.

```
std::vector<char> rerolling( pos.size() ); // can be reused if you zero it
for (int i = 0; i < get_pair_count(n); ++i) {
  auto&& [Ball, otherBall] = get_ball_pair(i);
   if (distance(pos[Ball], pos[otherBall]) <= R[Ball] + R[otherBall]) {
     rerolling[Ball] = 1; // I did this to Ball, not otherBall, on purpose
   }
}
```

and then a second loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rerolling.size(); ++i) {
  if (rerolling[i])
    pos[i] =  { randDouble(xRange), randDouble(yRange), randDouble(zRange) }
}
```

This is getting closer.

The next problem is the write to rerolling -- we have to ensure that only one thread writes to each index.  The easy way is to ensure that each thread gets a set of `Ball`s that are unique to it.

The partition of the triangle gets interesting, but the first row contains a fraction of at most 2/(n-1) of the entire work set.

Ah, we can use some fancy math.  As it happens, the length of the *first* row plus the length of the *last* row is (n-1).  The length of the *second* row plus the length of the *second last* row is also (n-1).  Etc.

So our "task units" can be to do the kth row and the (n-k)th row (roughly).  That provides n/2 equal size task units, and none have overlapping "Ball" values.

We now rewrite the first loop:

```
std::vector<char> rerolling( pos.size() ); // can be reused if you zero it
auto do_row = [&rerolling, &pos, &R, n]( int Ball ) {
  for (int otherBall = Ball+1; otherBall < n; ++otherBall)
    if (distance(pos[Ball], pos[otherBall]) <= R[Ball] + R[otherBall])
      rerolling[Ball] = 1; // I did this to Ball, not otherBall, on purpose
};
for (int i = 0; i < (n+1)/2; ++i) {
  do_row(i);
  do_row(n-1-i);
}
```

there we go -- (almost) equal sized non-overlapping work units consisting of two `do_row` calls.

Then a simple to thread reroller:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rerolling.size(); ++i) {
  if (rerolling[i])
    pos[i] =  { randDouble(xRange), randDouble(yRange), randDouble(zRange) }
}
```

as we saw above.

This is the hard work.

The easy work is finding a threading solution to work on these tasks.  Open MP, C++17 parallel algorithms, PPL, TBB, or write your own thread pool.

If you roll your own thread pool, use  [std::thread::hardware_concurrency()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) work out how many threads to launch.

[Here is one of many toy thread pools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42282654/1774667) I have posted to SO over the years.

Comment: Thank you for the large effort here, and as someone else pointed out as well, I do now see that I need a second loop to move everything at the end. My intended question should be clearer now that I edited it. I don't feel like it warrants a non-std library. I'm working on a function to do it right now, and will post it unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your for loop into a function that takes iterator start and end and its arguments.

```
int customForLoop(int start, int end)
{
    for (int Ball = start; Ball < end; Ball++)
    {
        // the work you want parallelized.
    }
}
```

Gets the number of threads on the hardware being used.

```
        unsigned hardwareThreadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

Initialize a vector to store threads in.

```
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
```

Calculate even chunks of loop.

```
        int loopChunk = balls / hardwareThreadCount; // Obviously won't always divide evenly, but it just needs to be close.
        for (int i = 0; i < hardwareThreadCount; i++)
        {
```

Launch a thread where the iterator controls the range, and the final thread launching loop goes to the max range of the array you are iterating through, so you don't miss any due to the chunking, such as:

```
if (i < hardwareThreadCount - 1)
            {
                threads.emplace_back(customForLoop,loopChunk * i, loopChunk * (i + 1));
            }
            else 
            {
                threads.emplace_back(customForLoop,loopChunk * i, balls);
            }
```